# my likelihood value resulted from gmm is correct?

Tags: speech-recognition, k-means, gaussian, mfcc

I'm making a program emotion-recognition in speech.

Using a mfcc + K-mean + GMM, I got a likelihood like -15012, -43400, -8000

It was so bigger value than I though. Is it right value?

Wave file's length usually 2~3 and I init using below option.

```
MFCC option 
SampleRate = 16000 
WindowSize = 256 
NumberCoefficients = 13
UseFirstCoefficient = true 
MinFreq = 20.0 
MaxFreq = 16000.0 
NumberFilters = 25 
K-Means Clustering default option 
NumberCluster = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual values of the likelihoods depend on many parameters used during feature extraction. For example, filterbank might be created in a different ways. They are different across different engines. So just looking on the values you can not say if they are correct or not.

Since you didn't mention the engine it's not possible to answer this question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your response was very helpful and I solved problem.